# How can I properly use my value as an argument to JComboBox.setModel()?

Tags: java, swing, exception, combobox, defaultlistmodel

In the code below, I attempted to create a `DefaultListModel` object to use for my `JComboBox`.

Apparently, the `setModel()` method only accepts a object that is a ComboBoxModel. I attempted to convert it, and I got the exception, `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

I already searched up how to fix this specific problem, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

I then tried to create a ComboBoxModel object instead, yet I learned that this class is abstract. How can I bypass this problem, and get the valid argument for `setModel()`?

```
private void setComboBoxYears(int numberOfYears, JComboBox comboBox) {
        DefaultListModel<Integer> years = new DefaultListModel<>();
        for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfYears; i++)
            years.addElement(i);
        comboBox.setModel((ComboBoxModel) years);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a [DefaultComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) instead.
2. Please have a look at the API as all of this information can be gleaned from it by a simple glance.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I will be sure to research the API too next time.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for solution then try in this way:

```
final JComboBox<Integer> comboBox = new JComboBox<Integer>();
Integer[] years = new Integer[numberOfYears];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfYears; i++)
    years[i] = i + 1;

comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer>(years));
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the solution.

Comment: You're welcome. Try to avoid RAW type. always use Generics as missed `ComboBoxModel` here. You are casting a generic type to non generic type.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie. What is a RAW type?

Comment: without any type such as `new ArrayList()` where type is missing. Make it generic such as `new ArrayList<Integer>()` Read more here [Java Tutorial on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)